# I need help understanding this 3 process deadlock graph

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm trying to understand this deadlock graph.  It appears there are 3 processes trying to insert at the same time.  What I'm not really understanding is why the processes are deadlocking.  I would have thought that the database would block 2 processes wait for 1 process to finish and then continue inserting.

The xml is too large to paste into this question so I've pasted it at http://pastebin.com/8dBVwftx.

Thanks in advance for your help.  We're waiting on a DBA to start so I'm trying to figure this stuff out on my own.

Comment: my analysis doesn't hold good with those spids

Comment: So I've looked again and note that the addition processes that are trying to insert have a transaction and the one that was deadlocked does not.  The PK is an identity so would it be caused by multiple processes trying to insert and getting assigned the same PK value?

Comment: Probably you have missing indexes. Add execution plans for your joins.